# Check value within range in Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have some specific count value and I have to check if that count lies within what range. The ranges are specified in the below table. For example,if the count value is >= 1 AND less than 250001 from the range_start column then the count lies with range_id 1, if count >= 250001 and count < 500001 then It lies within the range_id 2.

For the last range, it would just be count >= 50000001 and it would fall in range_id 13.

[image]

I have to apply the specific fees according to the range. I can't think of the best way to achieve this using a SQL Server stored procedure. Please help, thanks in advance.

Comment: And your expected results.

Comment: @DaleK to be honest, I had no idea how to achieve it.

Comment: You gotta do the research, check out some tutorials, other questions on SO etc. If someone does the work for you, you aren't learning how do to it for yourself.

Comment: @DaleK Thanks for the suggestion, you are totally right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the window function `LEAD` to find the next range end date as follows:

```
select t.* from
(select t.*, lead(range_start) over (order by range_start) as range_end
  from your_table t) t
where your_count_value >= range_start 
  and (your_count_value < range_end or range_end is null)
```

Comment: how can I get t.auth_fees and other columns into variable or how can I access them?

Comment: We have used t.* so you will get every data of the lower range row. If you want it in variable then you can use `@var = t.auth_fees`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `order by` and `top`:

```
select top (1) t.*
from t
where @value >= range_start
order by range_start desc
```